# How to do the upgrade from navigation reaction 4 to navigation 5 in this simple code

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

This is the code that I want to upgrade

This function:

```
function AddNotes({ navigation }) {
  const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState("");
  const [noteDescription, setNoteDescription] = useState("");

  function onSaveNote() {
    navigation.state.params.addNote({ noteTitle, noteDescription });
    navigation.goBack();
  }
```

Error in message:

> undefined in not an object evaluting navigation.state.params

Error in console:

> Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state, which can
> break usage such as persisting and restoring state. This might happen
> if you passed non-serializable values such as function, class
> instances etc. in params. If you need to use components with callbacks
> in your options, you can use 'navigation.setOptions' instead. See
> https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting#i-get-the-warning-non-serializable-values-were-found-in-the-navigation-state
> for more details.
>
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:71:8 in console.warn
> - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:18:23 in warn
> - node_modules@react-navigation\core\src\BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:258:10 in React.useEffect$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16921:31
>   in commitHookEffectList
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16970:29
>   in commitPassiveHookEffects
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15
>   in invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36
>   in invokeGuardedCallback
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:20061:28
>   in flushPassiveEffectsImpl
>
> - [native code]:null in flushPassiveEffectsImpl
>
> - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:643:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19597:25
>   in scheduleCallback$argument_1
> - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:482:68 in flushTask
> - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:607:20 in flushWork
> - node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:58:18 in _flushCallback
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:146:14 in _callTimer
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:399:17 in callTimers
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47
>   in __callFunction
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26
>   in __guard$argument_0
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10
>   in __guard
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17
>   in __guard$argument_0
>
> - [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Answer (score 0):

In React Navigation 5, you can access your callback functions in `route.params`

```
function AddNotes({ navigation, route }) {
  const [noteTitle, setNoteTitle] = useState("");
  const [noteDescription, setNoteDescription] = useState("");

  function onSaveNote() {
    const { params: { addNote } } = route;
    addNote({ noteTitle, noteDescription });
    navigation.goBack();
  }
```